# Can I put work in my portfolio that I conceptualized but someone else executed?

Tags: portfolio

I recently worked on an advertising project during a freelance gig, and presented an illustration concept. The client selected the concept and hired a professional illustrator to execute. Once the final illustration is complete and published, is it considered bad practice to include it in my portfolio, as long as I present it side-by-side with the concept and include a caveat that this was illustrated by someone else and link to their website/portfolio?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're couldn't do this, most web designers would have nothing to show

Answer (score 8):

Absolutely! It might be a good idea to drop the Illustrator a line about what you're publishing. That way, they won't be surprised when they see their work in someone else's portfolio.

There is **one caveat**, though: You should own the rights to publish the work (your own). Review the conditions of the contract you worked under (possibly your own ones) for this job and ensure that you are legally allowed to display the work you did under that contract. Note that that doesn't have to include you owning the copyrights of it.

I have a standard clause in my Terms and Conditions that legally allows me to display all work I do, even if the customer and I agree to actually transfer the copyrights to the customer. My default is that I keep the copyrights, not they.

Comment: This is good, though do note that one does not need to own the copyright to put something in their portfolio. You *do* have to watch out for NDAs and the like, though.